# Define custom keys for graphicx

Tags: graphics, key-value

I would like to define some shorthand keys for `includegraphics[]{}` like so:

`fullwidth -> width=\textwidth`, `halfwidth -> width=0.5\textwidth` etc.

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: I think this is not as easy to do as you might be used to from tikz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following adds `halfwidth` and `fullwidth` keys to the set of keys associated with `\includegraphics` (under the `Gin` family). `halfwidth` is equivalent to `width=0.5\linewidth` by default (internally setting `\Gin@ewidth`), while `fullwidth` is equivalent to `width=\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=2in,vmargin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
% Add halfwidth key (default is 0.5\linewidth)
\define@key{Gin}{halfwidth}[0.5\linewidth]{%
  \def\Gin@ewidth{#1}}
% Add fullwidth key (default is \linewidth)
\define@key{Gin}{fullwidth}[\linewidth]{%
  \def\Gin@ewidth{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Half width via \texttt{width}}
  
  \medskip
  
  \includegraphics[halfwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Half width via \texttt{halfwidth}}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Half width via \texttt{width}}
  
  \medskip
  
  \includegraphics[fullwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Half width via \texttt{fullwidth}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In general, adding keys to the existing family is not that hard. You'll just have to see how it fits in with the existing framework. For example, since `halfwidth` and `fullwidth` is related to `width`, searching for how `width` is handled in [`graphicx.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/graphicx.dtx) and how to manage keys with a default (if nothing else is specified) is how I went about this.

Comment: Thank you. Not quite as elegant as I hoped, but easy enough to implement for other 'shortcuts' I want to make as well. Can you define multiple ones with this method? eg. `fullrot -> width=\linewidth,rotate=90`?

Comment: I seem to get issues with floatrow, any thoughts on why that might be? EDIT: just need to wrap the arg in `{#1}`

Comment: @likethevegetable: Yes, it is possible to wrap multiple options into one. One would just need to figure out what keys are updated with the respective elements.

Comment: I was scratching my head really hard why your definitions of the keys use `\def\Gin@ewidth#1` instead of `\def\Gin@ewidth{#1}`, and I finally grasped it. This actually just works by coincidence because of some unexpected behaviour of `keyval` and the internal structure of the `\includegraphics` macro! Your definition of the keys `halfwidth` and `fullwidth` is actually faulty, you have to put a `%` after the default value or else your keys will take a space-delimited argument. So much for "In general, adding keys to the existing family is not that hard." :)

Comment: @Skillmon: Yes, quirky `keyval`.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks for the correction... just checked it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best shorthand is a simple LaTeX macro to simplify typesetting long and repetitive code, without having to patch a very common command, nor touch the `\@guts` of LaTeX, nor using external languages. For instance, if you use often images just taking the 50% and 100%  of the text width you can use:

```
\newcommand\halfimg[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{#1}}
\newcommand\fullimg[1]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}
```

and then:

```
\halfimg{example-image-a} \full{example-image-b}
```

Alternatively, if you print a bulk of images with very diferent widths, instead of make a macro for a few "standard" widths, you can use just one macro with an optional parameter. MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,parskip}
\newcommand\img[2][]{\includegraphics[width=#1\linewidth]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\img{example-image}
\img[.5]{example-image}
\img[.25]{example-image}
\img[.125]{example-image}
\img[.065]{example-image}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

You can make this also more complex, using macros with more than two arguments to allow set also another variable options as `angle`, but IMHO a shorthand should be simple, easy to type and easy to remember, Otherwise, is just easier use `\includegraphics` directly.

Comment: I try to avoid getting into the guts, but I would rather do that than make a new (or 12 new) macros. I think it's logical to have one and only one command include your graphics and extend the key-val interface--that's why key-vals are used in the first place

Comment: @likethevegetable LaTeX is a macro language, there are nothing wrong making new macros, but depend on your work flow. If you are typing again and again the same complex code, a new macro is not a good idea, it is a must.  To save you of a few keystrokes only once in a blue moon, hardly worth doing a macro nor anything else that you have to remember later (or even rediscover in old documents).